IIS 10.0 will not allow an application pool identity to be set to a valid Active Directory service account on .NET482
I have a series of production websites that are currently running 4.6 with IIS 10. I can set the application pool identity to an internal service account. I can also set WCF services to that service account.
On my development and test servers, which are running net48 with IIS 10, the IIS will not allow me to set the application pool with the same service account although I can set WCF services to that same account and it works in all other contexts.
I also can't set the application pool to my own Active Directory login, so it's not the service account. In both cases (service and personal AD account), the IIS interface says the password is incorrect.
On the development server, I can modify the applicationHost.config file to paste the information in from an account that works on the same server, but that doesn't work on my test server or any of my laptops running either Windows 10 or 11 with .NET Framework 4.8+ enabled or my test server.
When I do this on the IIS 10 with 4.8, IIS hangs and the application pool is shut down eventually.
I have tried to check the configurations (roles and features) to ensure the configuration of the system matches that of the working production server with net46, but it doesn't seem to be a configuration issue as far as I can identify although I am sure it involves how IIS handles encryption using 4.8 vs 4.6.
I have verified that the LoadUserProfile flag is set to true.
The way my applications work, I need to be able to set the application pool identity to a service account.
EDIT:
In response to some of the questions asked below, I have added some additional details.
The development server was created with net48 on it in 2020.  The problem began appearing in the last 3 months.
I was able to test the credentials using runas /userename:xxx cmd with a positive result.
I am also unable to set the credentials in a virtual directory setting on IIS.
On the development server, I was able to modify the applicationHost.config file to add the credentials to the application pool using other websites that had been added before and it worked fine.
On my test server, a laptop, that doesn't work.
I have tried setting the credentials via powershell, and while that method sets the credentials, they still do not work and either the application pool shuts down or the IIS GUI hangs when I try to view the application pools or sites.
Has anyone encountered with problem before (as in the last 3 or 4 months), and, if so, is there a solution to this problem?

Is the dev and test servers members of the same domain? Are you using the domain\username format?

IIS has no such problem, nor is it affected by the .NET Framework version. What does AD service account mean in this question? This specific phrase refers to a very specific type of restricted accounts, not just AD accounts used to run services.

.NET Framework 4.8 isn't new either. It was released almost 5 years ago. If there was any kind of problem, thousands of developers would have noticed a long time ago.

One difference between the servers is that the production server still has to allow TLS1 and TLS1.1 whereas it is disabled on the development and test servers.  The error I am consistently getting is that the password is incorrect and I know that is not the case.

The dev and test servers use a different domain than the production server, but this has always been the case and it has never been an issue before when setting the username/password combination in IIS.

The same question you have already posted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1690881/iis-10-0-will-not-allow-an-application-pool-identi.

Check the name of the poster.
I posted the question there as well.
